# PIP and PIP3 not working, says installing but error occurs everytime

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to use `import matplot.pyplot` in python but it says that the module does not exist, so as normal I run `pip3 install matplotlib`, but then everytime I run into this error:

```
➜  ~ pip3 install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.8.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (7.5 MB)
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1
  Using cached contourpy-1.1.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (232 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.4.5-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (66 kB)
Collecting pillow>=6.2.0
  Using cached Pillow-10.1.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (3.3 MB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Using cached cycler-0.12.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.3.1
  Using cached pyparsing-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
Collecting fonttools>=4.22.0
  Using cached fonttools-4.43.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl (2.7 MB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting importlib-resources>=3.2.0
  Using cached importlib_resources-6.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Collecting packaging>=20.0
  Using cached packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting numpy<2,>=1.21
  Using cached numpy-1.26.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (14.0 MB)
Collecting zipp>=3.1.0
  Using cached zipp-3.17.0-py3-none-any.whl (7.4 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Installing collected packages: zipp, six, numpy, python-dateutil, pyparsing, pillow, packaging, kiwisolver, importlib-resources, fonttools, cycler, contourpy, matplotlib
Successfully installed contourpy-1.1.1 cycler-0.12.1 fonttools-4.43.1 importlib-resources-6.1.0 kiwisolver-1.4.5 matplotlib-3.8.0 numpy-1.26.1 packaging-23.2 pillow-10.1.0 pyparsing-3.1.1 python-dateutil-2.8.2 six-1.16.0 zipp-3.17.0
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 806, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/private/var/folders/58/6kdshsgx3gj6k1pmsmst6fth0000gn/T/pip-target-5yt_jb8r/lib/python/packaging' -> '/Users/Bob/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/packaging'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 446, in run
    self._handle_target_dir(
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 505, in _handle_target_dir
    shutil.move(
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 822, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, copy_function=copy_function,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 557, in copytree
    return _copytree(entries=entries, src=src, dst=dst, symlinks=symlinks,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 458, in _copytree
    os.makedirs(dst, exist_ok=dirs_exist_ok)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/Bob/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/packaging'
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 23.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I've tried uninstalling, reinstalling pip3 and pip, as well as have tried:

```
brew unlink python3 && brew link python3
```

I deleted pip3 path so that it is the same path as python3 but still not effect.

Comment: Do you understand what it means for there to be a permission error? Do you have permission for that folder? Did you try running with elevated privileges? Seems that some folder in the `Users/Bob/Library/` path has some permission restrictions on it.

Comment: I deleted the folder, but for some reason it keeps wanting to use that folder after, it says `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/Bob'` but the file doesn't even exist.

Comment: check out the `--user` parameter of pip install.

Comment: I get this error now - `ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'`

Comment: Any real reason to install anything globally instead of using virtual environment?

Comment: Never got used to using virtual environments and I use these modules all the time.I already tried it on virtualenv, same error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do `pip3 install matplotlib --user` to install the module to install the package just for the current user, rather than for all users of the system

Comment: Already tried this, I get this error: `ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'`

Comment: @AbdollahHosseini those options are mutually exclusive; look up what they do. It would not make any sense for both to be run at the same time.

Comment: I don't understand either, I do not know how they are being ran both at the same time when all I am typing is `pip3 install matplotlib --user`. I am currently on the Sonoma public beta, could that be a reason?

Comment: You could try to install with elevated privileges using sudo.
`sudo pip3 install matplotlib --user`